# select row if NOT EXISTS condition after joining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, not-exists

DBMS: PostgreSql, but MySql is acceptable as well

I have 4 tables,

permissions

| id | slug | allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | create | true |
| 2 | edit | true |
| 3 | delete | true |
| 4 | edit | false |

roles

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | Manger |
| 3 | User |

model_permissions

| model_type | model_id | permission_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| users | 1 | 4 |
| roles | 1 | 1 |
| roles | 1 | 2 |
| roles | 1 | 3 |

model_roles

| model_type | model_id | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| users | 1 | 1 |
| users | 2 | 1 |
| users | 3 | 2 |
| users | 3 | 3 |

in the first step I want to get all permissions for user (let say id=1),  either 'direct' assigned or through the role,
this is what I come up, it works and returns correct result

```
select p.*
from permissions p
         join model_permissions mp on mp.permission_id = p.id
         join model_roles mr on mr.model_type = 'users' and mr.model_id = 1
where
    (
       (mp.model_type = 'users' and mp.model_id = 1)
        or
       (mr.role_id = mp.model_id and mp.model_type = 'roles')
    )

group by p.id;
```

my next step is to check if user has certain permission or not BUT if there is a row with same `slug` and `allowed=false` I want to get empty result.

example: user with id=1 has `edit` permission (allowed=true) through role, also has direct `edit` permission (allowed=false) id=4 (model_permissions table),

So when I'm trying to check if user has `edit` permission, in this particular case I want to get empty(false) result, what I have tried

```
select p.*
from permissions p
         join model_permissions mp on mp.permission_id = p.id
         join model_roles mr on mr.model_type = 'users' and mr.model_id = 1
where
     (
        (mp.model_type = 'users' and mp.model_id = 1)
        or
        (mr.role_id = mp.model_id and mp.model_type = 'roles')
     )
  and
    not exists(select *
                 from permissions p2
                 where p2.allowed=false
                 and p2.slug=p.slug
                 )
  and
    p.slug = 'edit'

group by p.id;
```

it works as expected BUT if I delete row from model_permissions `|users | 1  | 4  |` it still returns empty, I want to get result because this user has 'edit' permission throug role

I've tried sql queries above, also when I use `p2.id=p.id` inside `not exists` statment it always returnes result, the one with `allowed=true` value: `| 2 | edit | true |`

Any solution without changing db architecture

**UPDATE**

after several hours of thinking I found this query, which does what I was looking for, but still not sure why)

```
select p.*
from permissions p
         join model_permissions mp on mp.permission_id = p.id
where
    mp.model_type = 'roles' and mp.model_id = 1
  and
    not exists(select p2.*
                 from permissions p2
                 join model_permissions mp2 on mp2.permission_id = p2.id
                 where p2.allowed=false
                 and p2.slug=p.slug
                 )
  and
    p.slug = 'edit'
group by p.id;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the GROUP BY? (I'd expect an error - which dbms are you using?)

Comment: it's a postgres, group by is not that much important in this case,

Answer (score 0):

The revised should meet your needs

```
SELECT p.*
FROM permissions p
JOIN model_permissions mp ON mp.permission_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN model_permissions mp_direct ON mp_direct.permission_id = p.id AND mp_direct.model_type = 'users' AND mp_direct.model_id = 1
JOIN model_roles mr ON mr.model_type = 'users' AND mr.model_id = 1
WHERE
    -- Either direct user permission or through roles
    (
       (mp.model_type = 'users' AND mp.model_id = 1)
        OR
       (mr.role_id = mp.model_id AND mp.model_type = 'roles')
    )
    -- Ensure we're checking for the specific permission
    AND p.slug = 'edit'
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING
    -- Ensure there's no direct denial overriding the permission
    MAX(CASE WHEN mp_direct.allowed IS NOT NULL THEN mp_direct.allowed ELSE TRUE END)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, mp_direct doesn't have allowed collumn, it's in permissions table

Answer (score 0):

The problem basically comes down to the fact that `model_permissions` is a combiantion of two completely different tables. it's a denormalized design: you cannot have a conditional foreign key on different tables. (The same goes for `model_roles`, although what other models there are is not clear.)

This should have instead been two separate tables `user_permissions` and `role_permissions`. Then you would just use two separate `exists` clauses.

Finally, to get the results per `slug`, you need to `group by slug`, then use a `having` to filter out if you have `allowed=false` anywhere in the group.

```sql
select p.slug
from permissions p
where (
  exists (select 1
      from model_permissions mp
      where mp.model_type = 'users'
        and mp.model_id = 1
        and mp.permission_id = p.id
  )
  or exists (select 1
      from model_roles mr
      join model_permissions mp on mp.permission_id = p.id
      where mr.model_type = 'users'
        and mr.model_id = 1
        and mr.role_id = mp.model_id
        and mp.model_type = 'roles'
  )
)
group by
  p.slug
having count(*) filter (where not p.allowed) = 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/lDwA2V8k)

Comment: whole idea of model_roles and model_permissions is to have polymorphic relationship, this is part of package and developers can use any 'Model', in this case user is just an example, it can be admin and something else